# $document.ready() not working inside servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, servlets

I am using the javascript and html inside a `java servlet`. I am using get method to pass the parameters from jsp page to servlet and hence using the doGet method in the servlet.
The line:

```
out.println("$(document).ready(function{alert('Inside a function')});"); //is not working.
```

If I delete this statement the code runs fine i.e it alerts 1 and then 2.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
  out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>");
  out.println("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>");
  out.println("<head>"+"<link href='./styles/styles.css' type= 'text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>");
  out.println("<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");
  out.println("<script src='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.js' type='text/javascript' language='javascript'></script>");
  out.println("<link href='http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.rating.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>");           

out.println("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>");
out.println("alert('1');");                    out.println("$(document).ready(function{alert('Inside a function')});");             out.println("alert('2');");

out.println("</script>");  //closing the script tag

out.println("</body>"); //closing the body tag

out.println("</html>"); //closing the html tag

out.close();


}
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function{alert('Inside a function')});` isn't valid JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){alert('Inside a function')});
```